# Audiokit 4.5.2 - can't install via cocoa pods in Terminal

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audiokit

My app's deployment target is currently set to 9.2 in Xcode. I believe 9.0 should be minimum.

However when trying to update to AudioKit 4.5.2 (from 4.4) - I'm getting the following error in Terminal...

```
⇒  pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AudioKit":
  In Podfile:
AudioKit (~> 4.5.2)

Specs satisfying the `AudioKit (~> 4.5.2)` dependency were found, 
but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

What should I do? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question has already been given to you.

> Specs satisfying the `AudioKit (~> 4.5.2)` dependency were found,  but
>   they required a higher minimum deployment target.

This literally means you're trying to update to **v4.5.2** but that specific version requires a higher minimum deployment target, **should be higher than your iOS 9.2.**

> What should I do? Many thanks.

You have multiple options:

1. Target iOS 10 (or at least the v4.5.2's deployment target), if that's okay with your manager or team lead, or you.
2. Explicitly target AudioKit's lower version, like what you've mentioned, in your podfile, like so: `pod 'AudioKit', '4.4'`.

**UPDATE:**

I made a sample Xcode project and discovered that they haven't released **v4.5.2** for their cocoapods, well, as far as I know. So this should be in your podfile insted:

```
pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.0'
```

and make sure that you also have this line in your podfile, targeting your iOS version:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'd got that far, thanks 8•) - trying to find what the minimum deployment target is I guess. Is it really a big bump to 10.0? I'm currently using 4.4 but this has lots of issues, as outlined by AudioKit devs

Comment: Even in my current company, we decided to ditch the iOS 9 for easier development :) I recommend it too if you do not want to fix the AudioKit 4.4 yourself for iOS 9.0 (if it's possible). Remember to select an answer to close this thread :)

Comment: Hmmm - just increased minimum deployment target to 10.0 (In Xcode > Project > General > Deployment Info). Then ran ```pod install```. I'm getting exactly the same issue... So what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, some needed APIs somehow disappeared after the switch to Swift 4.2 in the latest AudioKit 4.5, which forced us to require iOS 10 as a minimum. iOS 9 users are a very tiny fraction of your users at this point realistically though.

Comment: Regarding your update section, I just pushed up to our staging build which should update the specs repository that we host on AudioKit.